# C# - Using a lambda to specify non-default params

Tags: c#, lambda, parameter-passing, anonymous-function, optional-parameters

I'm building a library which contains a series of methods, each of which has several overloads which I'm trying to simplify.

Many of the methods have recurring overload options. For example

```
AddString(string option1)
AddString(string option1, int option2)
AddString(string option1, int option2, bool option3)

AddArray(string option1)
AddArray(string option1, int option2)
AddArray(string option1, int option2, bool option3)
```

Now, I know that I can specify those as default parameters - parameters with a specified default value. I don't want to do this because I want the defaults to be configurable from project to project, or even from caller to caller.

I also realise that I could build an `Options` object which has the (configurable) defaults, and the user could pass an instance of that to another overload like so

```
var options = new Options();
options.OptionProperty1 = "A new string";
AddString(options);
```

But what I'd prefer is to have a static `Options` object which contained the defaults for all the parameters, and *somehow* specify only the changes in an inline call, like so

```
AddString(options => options.Set(
                            OptionProperty1 = "A string",
                            OptionProperty2 = 1,
                            OptionProperty3 = true
                        ));
```

Is this possible, and if so then what would the method signature look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have a `Set` method like you're after it would have to have a parameter for each option you wanted to set, which will probably get unwieldy after time,

You can opt for a fluent interface which should give you want you want. For example:

```
class Options
{
  Options Option1(string value)
  {
    m_Option1 = value;
    return this;
  }

  Options Option2(int value)
  {
    m_Option2 = value;
    return this;
  }
}
```

Now `AddString` would look like this:

```
AddString(options = > options.Option1("A String").Option2(1)));
```

And the implementation of `AddString` would look like this:

```
public void AddString(Action<Options> optionConfig)
{
  var options = new Options();
  optionConfig(options);

  // rest of method
}
```

Alternatively you could have the caller create the `Options` instance. This would allow them to set the properties directly:

```
class Options
{
  public string Option1{get;set;}
  public int Option2{get;set;}
}
```

And now the caller can say:

```
AddString(() = > new Options{Option1="A String", Option2=1});
```

Where `AddString` looks like this:

```
public AddString(Func<Options> optionsCreator)
{
  Options options = optionsCreator();

  // rest of method
}
```

Comment: I very much like your suggestion - but what would the AddString method signature look like?

Comment: @awj - I've added an example

Comment: I like this approach as well. If you take a look at devexpress tools they take an approach very similar to this and it works very well.

Comment: I'm not sure why, in the AddString example implementation, you instantiate Options and then pass this into `optionConfig`.

Comment: @awj - because the caller of the method needs an instance to set the properties on. In your example in the question you're also doing the same thing. The other option would be to have the lambda create an instance on `Options` and will in the option values.

Comment: @awj - I've added another example

Comment: Thanks for the clarity and the examples @Sean. It makes sense, though I think I prefer the first example over the second.